# Need your suggestion for Exchange ActiveSync client

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010, activesync

I'm just about to start building MS Exchange ActiveSync client. I found two type of implementations. I don't know which one is the right approach.

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_exchangeprotocols/thread/3b1e73fc-b69a-4ed2-a905-d15af6666f22
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361570%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx

First option says that the command being sent to my Exchange server (from my iPhone mail app) and **the body is not xml encoded**. I really didn’t find any other standard documentation regarding ActiveSync *without using encoded xml*.

Second option says to use WBXML and ActiveSync HTTP to perform the right action. It seams very well documented.

I'm really confused while thinking what should be the right approach to perform actions like SendMail, Reply, Forward, mark Read/Unread etc..

Can you guys guide me to select right basic approach which supports all versions of exchange servers with minimal change (Exchange 2007, 2010 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Exchange ActiveSync, I believe you are building a PDA Mail client ? If yes, you can use WBXML approach.

For example, if you are building a Android application in phoneGap, then you can resolve this issue by two approach. Either user [KXML](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/) java parser to parser, encode and decode wbxml, xml or a javascript approach with [this](https://github.com/asutherland/jsas) library.